# Where can i find a full list of InputeFilters Zend2 properties?

Tags: properties, zend-framework2, structure, input-filter

Where i can find a complit list of validator construction properties (factory). For exmple we got 1 inputeFilter 'email':

```
 $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'email',
        'required' => true,
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                'options' => array(
                    'domain' => true,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

May be some documentation with all properties ('name', 'requiered. e.t.c.) and their structure.

Answer (score 0):

they are all well documented just not in the array notation http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html

also you can view the invokables in the vendor code the variable is called $invokableClasses.

```
..\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Validator\ValidatorPluginManager.php
```

For options you may still look at the documentation since they obviously vary from validator to validator.

Edit: In some cases building the validator out of the array notation is helpful. You'll just have to add them into the inputfilter notation like so:

```
...
$eanValidator = new Zend\Validator\Barcode(array(
   'adapter'  => 'EAN13',
   'checksum' => false,
));
...
$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'ean-test',
    'required' => true,
    'validators' => array(
        array(
            $eanValidator,
            $someOtherValidator,
            ...
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: i got this. but still may be there are some examples in the array notation for most of cases? it would be nice. i have seen that documantation but there are no explane what and where write to....

Comment: at fact alternative is shoter? and i can add them throw __construct method?